# How to resize images in a directory?

Tags: java, image-processing, foreach, javax.imageio, imgscalr

This code attempts to resize images in a directory called "imgs". Unfortunately for some reason when I uncomment the listFiles(..) loop `ImageIO.read(sourceImageFile)` will return null. Yet processing the same file straightaway outside the loop (`res("imgs/foto_3.jpg")`) works. So apparently, this loop is preventing the files from being read. Solutions?

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import static org.imgscalr.Scalr.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
//        for (File sourceImageFile : new File("imgs").listFiles()) {
//            res("imgs/"+sourceImageFile.getName());
//        }
        res("imgs/foto_3.jpg");

    }

    public static void res(String arg) throws IOException {

        File sourceImageFile = new File(arg);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(sourceImageFile);

        BufferedImage thumbnail = resize(img, 500);

        thumbnail.createGraphics().drawImage(thumbnail, 0, 0, null);
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "jpg", new File("resized/" + sourceImageFile.getName()));
    }
}
```

[image]

To reproduce the problem you can [download the Maven project](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/23278095/ImgResizer.zip).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've changed res method:

```
public static void res(File arg) throws IOException {
        if (arg.contains(".DS_Store")) {
            return;
        }
```

A mac-issue (or should filter non-image files, as was suggested)!

Answer (score 2):

Can you change `res` to accept a `File` object rather than a String? Then you could write the following, which is a lot nicer:

```
for (File sourceImageFile : new File("imgs").listFiles()) {
    res(sourceImageFile);
}
```

As to your original question, try adding some tracing statements or using a debugger to find what exactly gets passed to `res`.

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured it out. now it's working.
You (or whoever created the downloadable project u pasted here) are using Mac OS, and it automatically creates a .DS_Store file.
When you try to pass it to the res method, it doesn't know how to handle a non-image file and acts as null.

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        for (File sourceImageFile : new File("imgs").listFiles()) {
            if (sourceImageFile.getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
                res(sourceImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }
```

This is the modified void main method. it works, u can refine the if statement for more in depth filtering of wrong files.
Also I changed the argument given to the res method. it looks better now, as getAbsoulutePath returns the name and the path.
Let me know how it worked

Comment: can u edit and add the resize method to the code? I want to experiment with it

Comment: I've added a link with the project code so that you can download it and see for yourself.

Comment: La bla 'resize' is statically imported from imgscalr.

Comment: I had the problem when trying it. found the problem.It now works. see my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why the file listing iteration would mess with the thumbnail generation, but you mentioned privately to me that you were using [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) and were curious what the correct code to batch-process a directory would look like, so I wrote up this example code for you.

The code below will process any directory (`imgs` is hard-coded to stay consistent with your example code) and write it out to any other directory (`resized` is used to stay consistent -- feel free to change either directory)

```
import static org.imgscalr.Scalr.*;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ScaleDirExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File[] images = new File("imgs").listFiles();

        for (File f : images) {
            System.out.println("Processing: " + f.getName() + "...");

            if (f.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("\tSkipping, file is a directory...");
                continue;
            } else
                process(f);
        }
    }

    private static void process(File file) throws IOException {
        // Load image.
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);

        // Resize image.
        image = resize(image, 500);

        // Save the resized image as the thumbnail.
        saveThumbnail(file, image);
    }

    private static void saveThumbnail(File originalFile, BufferedImage thumbnail)
            throws IOException {
        String filename = originalFile.getName();

        // Determine file extension.
        String fileExt = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

        // Save the thumbnail to the resized dir.
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, fileExt, new File("resized/" + filename));
    }
}
```

The call to `resize(image, 500)` can be modified to match any of the [Scalr.resize methods](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html#resize%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20int,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp...%29) - you can pass filters or improve quality if you want.

Example output from my test setup looks like:

```
Processing: flower-dog-gimp.jpg...
Processing: flower-dog.jpg...
Processing: logoOXdaComida.png...
Processing: mr-t-thumbnail.jpg...
Processing: mr-t.jpg...
Processing: problem-trans-peter-griffin.png...
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Riyad. Your code uses the same loop. It works for you, it doesn't work for me! See my answer.

Comment: @simpatico When you take my code and copy-paste it into a new class and run it in your project, does it work? If not, is there anything unique about the dirs you are processing? for example, don't exist, read/write permission issue, or a network mount?

Answer (score 0):

One obvious way to debug this to output the specific `sourceImageFile` that `ImageIO.read(..)` is returning null on. I suspect its because listFiles will give you a list of all files and directories that are in the image directory. [listFiles javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28%29). You can prevent that by using a FileFilter that makes sure that listFiles only returns files and additionally files of the right type.

An example of a file filter that only returns file is below:

```
import java.io.FileFilter
class RegularFilesOnlyFileFilter implements FileFilter {
   public boolean accept(File pathName) {
       return pathName.isFile();
   }
}
```

The way to use this filter is this - `new File("imgs").listFiles(new RegularFilesOnlyFilesFilter())`