# Enlarging image using GD results in dismal quality compared to Scalr (JAVA)

Tags: java, php, image, resize, bicubic

I have been dealing with very small images and I have tried to discover the best way to increase them. I compared two different sources: imagecopyresampled (PHP: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) versus Scalr (JAVA: [How to resize images in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779563/how-to-resize-images-in-a-directory)). I am including the codes that I am using below for the sake of completeness, but they are strongly based on other threads or sites referenced above. If someone thinks that I should remove, I will do that! In both sources it seems that the algorithm used to deal with the issue seems to be the same: Bicubic interpolation. **However, in the case of the JAVA source, the quality of the resized image is MUCH MUCH better in my implementation (it is not even possible to compare). Am I doing something wrong when I am using the PHP source?** If not, does anyone can explain me the difference between them?

**JavaCode:**

```
import java.awt.image.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import static org.imgscalr.Scalr.*;

public class App2 {

       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            for (File sourceImageFile : new File("imgs").listFiles()) {
                if (sourceImageFile.getName().endsWith(".jpg"))
                    res(sourceImageFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }


    public static void res(String arg) throws IOException {

        File sourceImageFile = new File(arg);
        BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(sourceImageFile);

        BufferedImage thumbnail = resize(img, 500);

        thumbnail.createGraphics().drawImage(thumbnail, 0, 0, null);
        ImageIO.write(thumbnail, "jpg", new File("resized/" + sourceImageFile.getName()));
    }
}
```

**PHP code:**

```
<?php
// The file
$filename = 'photos/thePhoto.jpg';

// Set a maximum height and width
$width = 250;
$height = 250;

// Content type
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');

// Get new dimensions
list($width_orig, $height_orig) = getimagesize($filename);

$ratio_orig = $width_orig/$height_orig;

if ($width/$height > $ratio_orig) {
   $width = $height*$ratio_orig;
} else {
   $height = $width/$ratio_orig;
}

// Resample
$image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width_orig, $height_orig);

// Output
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
?>
```

Just to be clear, in the JAVA code, I have to keep the images in a folder. In the PHP code, I provide the name of the file. Off course, I compared exactly the same image. Furthermore, both codes are running without any kind of problem.

![PHP versus Java (in this order)]: http://www.facebook.com/media/set/?set=a.122440714606196.1073741825.100005208033163&type=1&l=55d93c4969

Comment: Hmm, interesting. There shouldn't be *that* much of a difference at 100% quality. Can you show example images? (Edit: oh, I notice you are *enlarging* images. That's a different story... but I guess it'd be best if you could show some examples)

Comment: I updated my question with a public image! When the size of the images increase, the difference is larger!

Comment: Re the examples - ah. The Java code is using a strong blur filter to hide the damage done by the enlargement. That isn't readily available in PHP's GD as far as I know. Can you use ImageMagick instead? (either as a standalone executable, or the PHP library)

Comment: @Pekka웃, it seems to be a relevant information. I have never used, but I will try to compare with the imageMagik!